# if/else in mysql not really working - syntax

Tags: mysql, if-statement, syntax

Is it possible to do the following in MYSQL without a stored procedure:

```
SET @q='10';
SET @p='5';
SELECT @a_rows := COUNT(*) FROM 'main1' WHERE status='0' && price<= @p && quantity >     '0';

IF @a_rows = '0' THEN

INSERT INTO detail1 (quantity,price,status) VALUES (@q,@p,'0');
INSERT INTO detail2 (quantity,price,status) VALUES (@q,@p,'0');

ELSEIF @a_rows='1' THEN
INSERT INTO detail3 (quantity,price,status) VALUES (@q,@p,'0');

ELSE 
; 
ENDIF
```

It always returns error #1064

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that is not possible.

You need a shell around these instructions like a procedure, trigger or function. Only a single query can run alone in MySQL.